# Unable to get n gram word cloud in R

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud for bi-gram (and higher n grams) using the below code -

```
text_input <- scan("Path/Wordcloud.txt")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text_input))
corpus.ng = tm_map(corpus,removeWords,c(stopwords(),"s","ve"))
corpus.ng = tm_map(corpus.ng,removePunctuation)
corpus.ng = tm_map(corpus.ng,removeNumbers)
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
tdm.bigram = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus.ng,control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
tdm.bigram
freq = sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm.bigram)),decreasing = TRUE)
freq.df = data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)
head(freq.df, 20) 
pal=brewer.pal(8,"Blues")
pal=pal[-(1:3)]
wordcloud(freq.df$word,freq.df$freq,max.words=100,random.order = F, colors=pal)
```

I have seen similar code on few websites being used for generating n gram but I am getting only single word combinations in my output.

[image: Plot]

The code is not responding to changes in min and max being set to different values (2,3,4 etc) successively in the NGramTokenizer function.
Am I missing something in the code or is it possible that one of the libraries which I am calling  in the code (tm,ggplot2,wordcloud,RWeka) or their dependencies (like rJava) is not responding? I will be really grateful if someone can throw some pointers regarding this issue or suggest modifications in the above code.

Thanks,
Saibal

Comment: Others have had problems.  A recent items on R-Bloggers analyzed inaugural addresses of the US Presidents and ended up using the quanteda package for bigrams.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out on `mentioning the token delimiter`.

```
token_delim <- " \\t\\r\\n.!?,;\"()"
BigramTokenizer <- NGramTokenizer(mycorpus, Weka_control(min=2,max=2, delimiters = token_delim))
```

This should work.

In case you need a working example, you can check this five-minute video:
https://youtu.be/HellsQ2JF2k

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, some others have had problems using the Corpus function.
Try using the volatile corpus
corpus <- **VCorpus**(VectorSource(text_input))

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked:

```
> minfreq_bigram<-2
> bitoken <- NGramTokenizer(corpus, Weka_control(min=2,max=2))
> two_word <- data.frame(table(bitoken))
> sort_two <- two_word[order(two_word$Freq,decreasing=TRUE),]
> wordcloud(sort_two$bitoken,sort_two$Freq,random.order=FALSE,scale = 
c(2,0.35),min.freq = minfreq_bigram,colors = brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"),max.words=150)
```